# How to convert a Word DOCX to an HTML in Python with all images embedded

Tags: python, html, docx

I have tried a number of solutions that convert a Word document DOCX to an HTML file, but these solutions also generate an extra folder containing the images of the (DOCX) HTML. Is there a way to avoid that extra folder and still be possible to display all images in the HTML file? I need only 1 file (HTML), because I have to copy it over to another location without any extra folder.

Below is a screenshot of how the Word document looks. It contains a table with 2 columns and 3 rows and a couple of images:
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To convert a Word DOCX to an HTML in Python with all images embedded, you can use the `python-docx`, `lxml` and `base64` libraries.

Example:

```
from docx import Document
from lxml import etree
from base64 import b64encode

doc = Document('path/document.docx')

# create an empty HTML element
html_element = etree.Element('html')

# create the head element
head_element = etree.SubElement(html_element, 'head')
title_element = etree.SubElement(head_element, 'title')
title_element.text = 'Document Title'

# create the body element
body_element = etree.SubElement(html_element, 'body')

# loop through all paragraphs in the document
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    # create a new paragraph element
    para_element = etree.SubElement(body_element, 'p')
    
    # loop through all runs in the paragraph
    for run in para.runs:
        # add the text to the paragraph element
        if para_element.text is not None:
            para_element.text = para_element.text + run.text
        else:
            para_element.text = run.text
    
    # loop through all images in the paragraph
    for inline in para.runs:
        if inline.element.tag == '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing}inline':
            for graphic in inline.element.iter('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture}graphic'):
                for graphic_data in graphic.iter('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture}blipFill'):
                    # get the image data
                    image_data = graphic_data.xpath('.//a:blip/@r:embed', namespaces={'a': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main', 'r': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships'})[0]
                    
                    # get the image file name
                    image_filename = doc.part.related_parts[image_data].partname.replace('/media/', '')
                    
                    # read the image data
                    with doc.part.related_parts[image_data].open() as image_file:
                        image_data = image_file.read()
                    
                    # create an image element
                    img_element = etree.SubElement(para_element, 'img')
                    img_element.set('src', f"data:image/png;base64,{b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')}")
                    img_element.set('alt', image_filename)

# create the HTML file
with open('path/document.html', 'w') as html_file:
    html_file.write(etree.tostring(html_element, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get an error msg for the line "para_element.text = para_element.text + run.text" that cannot be concatenated. I tried to contain both in "str()" but I get an empty HTML file. Any suggestions?

Comment: (To Kamil) The problem is that the variables return a None value. I modified the line by using the function "join(filter(None, (para_element.text, run.text)))". I still get an empty HTML file.

Comment: @sugarakis If you're getting an error message saying that `NoneType` object is not iterable, it's because the `text` attribute of the `para_element` is `None`. This can happen if the paragraph doesn't have any text. To fix this, you can add a check to make sure that the `para_element.text` is not `None` before concatenating the `run.text` to it.

Comment: @sugarakis I edited my first answer and modified code. I hope this will help!

Comment: I edited my question with a screenshot of the Word document I am trying to process. I appreciate your edited answer, however somehow I get None results in the "para.runs" loop. I added a print debug and I get "para_element.text: None" 3 times. Most probably one time per table row? Thanx again

Comment: I have heard that Microsoft puts lots of hidden characters in their text formats - if this is correct, I'd imagine these need to be stripped or otherwise accounted for?

Comment: @MarcHolman Yes, Sir! It's true that Microsoft Word documents can contain hidden characters, such as formatting and markup tags, that may affect the appearance of the document when it's converted to HTML. These characters may not be visible in the Word document itself, but they can be present in the underlying XML structure of the document.